# Isolate XML tag

Tags: xml, vbscript, tags

Is it possible to get the XML by tagname in VBScript? For example, if I have the following XML:

```
<MAIN>
<returnXML>
  <Row ID="21" Name="counting stars" Description="test" TypeID="1" ActivationDate="2014-02-11T00:00:00" IncludeTaskGroupCommentBit="0" IncludeTaskItemCommentBit=""/>
</returnXML>
<AEDZ><x id="templateID" val="14"/><x id="name" val="Aedz"/><x id="desc" val="test"/><x id="typeID" val="1"/><x id="ver" val="1"/>
</AEDZ>
</MAIN>
```

Now what I want to do is store the XML of just the tag `<AEDZ>` in a variable `X`, so that the value of `x` will be like this:

```
<AEDZ>
  <x id="templateID" val="14"/><x id="name" val="Aedz"/><x id="desc" val="test"/><x id="typeID" val="1"/><x id="ver" val="1"/>
</AEDZ>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the XML text of any selected node via the node's `xml` property:

```vbs
Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xml.async = False
xml.load "C:\path\to\your.xml"

If xml.parseError <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo xml.parseError.reason
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

x = xml.selectSingleNode("//AEDZ").xml

WScript.Echo x
```